# Getting 401 error when call $http POST and passing data

Tags: angularjs, windows-authentication, angularjs-service

I am calling a Web API 2 backend from an angularjs client.  The backend is using windows authentication and I have set up the $httpProvider to use credentials with all calls and it works fine for all GETS.

Like this:
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true

But, when using the POST verb method AND passing a data js object I get a 401 error.  If I remove the data object from the $http.post call it reaches the endpoint but I would like to pass up the data I need to save.

Here's an example of the client-side call:

```
var saveIndicator = function (indicator) {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl + "/api/indicators",
            data: indicator
        };

        return $http(req).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Show some code please. When you do a POST-Rquest you do not send the parameters in the Url - I don't know if you do that, but just that you know.

Comment: as you are getting 401, it is ofcourse authentication issue. Does your api requires some authentication header?

Comment: the web api requires authentication.  The authentication header is supplied by the $httpProvider being configured to "useCredentials".  A post request will work under this scenario until I add a data parameter, then I get the 401 exception.